# Using boost_unordered_hash_map with char* key

Tags: c++, boost, hashmap

I have a mix of C and C++ files that collectively form my program. I am using boost unordered hash map which I initially defined as:

```
typedef boost::unordered_map<char *, int> my_map;
```

However, the map was acting weird; find(key) could not find keys that actually existed in the hash map. I, then, changed the definition to:

```
typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string, int> my_map;
```

and now the hash map works fine. Nevertheless, it is inconvenient for me to convert my char * to std::string in order to use the map. Is there a way to make the first definition work?

Comment: do you have a minimal example?

Comment: The default comparator is probably `==`. Doesn't work for `char*` if you want to compare string values, you'll be comparing pointers instead. (That said, I haven't checked the docs.)

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because the key that is looked up is the pointer, not the stringof chars pointed to. With std::string you have the equality operator (==) work on the string content

Comment: How can I change the default comparison operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `std::unordered_map`

---

Oh aha. Noticed you wanted `unordered_map`. One of my favourites is to use `boost::string_ref` to represent strings without copying, so you could do

```
std::unordered_map<boost::string_ref, int> map;
```

with a quick & dirty hash implementation like:

```
namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<boost::string_ref> {
        size_t operator()(boost::string_ref const& sr) const {
            return boost::hash_range(sr.begin(), sr.end());
        }
    };
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa38c9ed4c0e023d)**

### `std::map`

---

You can use a custom comparator:

```
std::map<char const*, int, std::less<std::string> > map;
```

Note that this is highly inefficient, but it shows the way.

More efficient would be to wrap/use `strcmp`:

```
#include <cstring>

struct less_sz
{
    bool operator()(const char* a, const char* b) const
    {
        if (!(a && b))
            return a < b;
        else
            return strcmp(a, b) < 0;
    }
};
```

And then

```
std::map<char const*, int, less_sz> map;
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f64ed9cc8c4a0568)**

Comment: Oops. I missed the `unordered_` in your question. Added now.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the correction! However, when I use any f the solutions above for "std::map" I get an error stating wrong number of template arguments. The template is <class key, class T, class Compate, class Allocator>. I guess you're missing the allocator class above.

Comment: @NewToAndroid I'm not missing anything :) I even had the samples compiling live, so you can see that is the case. Apparently your compiler platform is a bit challenged, and yes, you might have to work around that. Although I know of no current compilers that would have a problem with this particular code.

Comment: You weren't missing anything, I was the one missing the include header :) Thanks for the answers which worked like magic!